# Property and Database Bar for PhpStorm

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpstorm

Does **PhpStorm** have **property bar** and **database** similar to dreamweaver? If yes, how to activate?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: 1) No 2) Yes - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Databases+and+SQL+Editor+in+PhpStorm  and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/databases-and-sql.html?search=database

Comment: @LazyOne And the property bar, do not you?

Comment: I already gave you "Yes" and links for DB .. and "No" for Properties. Do not know what else to clarify here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PHPStorm has Functionalities to Show Database in Sidebar.Before You need to connect Database in PHPStorm.

For Connecting Database in PHPStorm :
Check in **Right Side There is Database** Tab You Found Just **Click on '+' Button** and You **add Database**.
[See This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwg8y.png)
Now Test The Connection and Then Your Database will Display,
[See This Image For Checking DB Show in Database Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsHio.jpg)

Comment: On the database I've already set it up. I'm talking about the properties bar like in the image above, where it shows properties of html and others.

Comment: That Thing is Not Available in PHPStorm